# node.js, return the same promise for all callers until a promise is resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, memoization

I have a heavy promise function that gets called multiple times with the same parameters.
I want it to avoid re-running the same calculations for the same params. Instead, if a consecutive call has the same params, return the promise created by the previous one.

Normally, for such cases, I would use memoizee package (or memoize in lodash).
However, this promise returns a large dataset, which can be problematic to keep in memory. Since these packages cache the results in-memory, they won't be a good fit for this case.

An simplify example:

```
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

async function sleepOneSec() {
  console.log("going to sleep");
  await sleep(1000)
};

async function myApp() {
  await Promise.all([1, 2, 3].map(async item => {
    console.log('item', item);
    await sleepOneSec();
  }));
  console.log('promise.all is done');
  await sleepOneSec();
  console.log('completed');
}

myApp().then(() => {}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

currently, without any memoization, the output is:

```
item 1
going to sleep
item 2
going to sleep
item 3
going to sleep
promise.all is done
going to sleep
completed
```

Ideally I want the results to be:

```
item 1
going to sleep
item 2
item 3
promise.all is done
going to sleep
completed
```

Comment: Store the promise in some collection where it can be found via the parameters. Before you create a new promise, with a set of parameters, look in your storage, if there is already a promise for these parameters. If yes, return it, if no create a new one. Of course this will keep the result of the promise in memory. If you don't want that, write the result to a file, once the promise resolved and return a `readFile` or similar for later calls

Comment: Where's the function that has arguments where you want to combine the promise if the arguments are the same?  The only promise-returning functions you show are `sleep()` and `sleepOneSec()`.  Please show your real code, not some make-up code so we can address the real world issues you might have.  We also need to know what data type the arguments are and, if they are objects, exactly how they should be compared for equality.

Comment: @derpirscher, thanks, but it won't help. If I save the promise result in this collection, then, practically I cache it in-memory, which I don't want. Writing to a file is time consuming and needs serialization, which, in my case is super complex and not realistic.

Comment: @jfriend00, the real code is way too long for here, no one will bother reading it. It actually not very important. If you have a solution that doesn't handle the params that would be great. If the params are important, then you can replace `sleepOneSec()` with `sleepOneSec(num)` which returns the number it gets. All calls to this function pass the same parameter: "1".

Comment: So basically you don't want your results in memory and you can't write them to a file ... I run out of ideas where else to store them ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's an implementation for `sleepOneSec(num)` that generates the output you asked for.  It creates a cache for the promise from `sleepOneSec()` that is indexed by the arguments.  The promise is removed from the cache as soon as it resolves or rejects so it is only reused while "in progress":

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

const sleepCache = new Map();

async function sleepOneSec(num) {
    // serialize args
    const args = JSON.stringify({ num });
    let p = sleepCache.get(args);
    if (!p) {
        console.log("going to sleep");
        p = sleep(num);
        sleepCache.set(args, p);

        // when this promise resolves, remove it from the cache
        // so it won't be used any more
        const remove = () => sleepCache.delete(args);
        p.then(remove, remove);
    }
    return p;
}

async function myApp() {
    await Promise.all([1, 2, 3].map(async item => {
        console.log('item', item);
        await sleepOneSec(1000);
    }));
    console.log('promise.all is done');
    await sleepOneSec(1000);
    console.log('completed');
}

myApp().then(() => {}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

If the arguments to the function in question contain objects, then you have to make sure they are uniquely serializable with `JSON.stringify()` or you need to manually convert them into something that is representative of their uniqueness that is serializable by `JSON.stringify()`.  It's also important to manually handle serialization of any objects because `JSON.stringify()` does not necessarily stringify properties in the same order which would break the comparison.  This is why I asked about the arguments in your real code.  All you offered me when I asked about what the real arguments are was a single numeric argument so that's what is shown here.  But, if you have objects as arguments, those have to be handled carefully so the caching works properly.

Comment: Fantastic! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! I'm unsure what is the second `remove` here: `p.then(remove, remove);` I guess it could be: `p.then(remove);`. Regarding the params, I totally understand (I have done it many times before, so didn't want to add complexity here). Thanks again! :)

Comment: @David - `promise.then(resolveHandler, rejectHandler)` takes two arguments (the 2nd is optional).  If provided, the second argument is a rejectHandler.  You need to make sure you remove the promise from the cache when the promise is resolved OR rejected.

Comment: Oh that's right. I'm used to the `.then().catch()` syntax. Thanks for clarifying.